# How to parse potentially malformed xml to dataframe?

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, pandas

I have xml that looks like this from an API.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
import lxml.etree as et
from lxml import etree


 url = 'abc.com'

 xml_data1 = requests.get(url).content
 print(xml_data1)
```

xml_data1:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Leads>
      <Lead Id="123" LeadTitle="test, test.,  , (123) 456-7890, " CreateDate="01/01/2017 11:11:11" ModifyDate="01/04/2017 03:03:03" ACount="1" LCount="4" RCount="0" ROnly="false" Flagged="false" LastDistributionDate="01/01/2017 10:10:10" LeadFormType="test test">
    <Campaign CampaignId="123" CampaignTitle="abc" />
    <Status StatusId="123" StatusTitle="test" />
    <Agent AgentId="123" AgentName="test, test" AgentEmail="a@a.com">
      <AgentCustomFields custom1="test test, test" custom2="test" custom3="" custom4="" />
    </Agent>
    <Fields>
      <Field FieldId="7" Value="a@a.com" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="test" />
      <Field FieldId="8" Value="test" FieldTitle="test 1" FieldType="test" />
      <Field FieldId="9" Value="test" FieldTitle="City" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="10" Value="test" FieldTitle="State" FieldType="State" />
      <Field FieldId="11" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Zip" />
      <Field FieldId="950" Value="test." FieldTitle="Business Name" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1261" Value="Intuit Desktop" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1262" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1263" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Number" />
      <Field FieldId="1267" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1310" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Phone" />
      <Field FieldId="1319" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Number" />
      <Field FieldId="1485" Value="test" FieldTitle="tst" FieldType="State" />
    </Fields>
    <Logs>
      <StatusLog>
        <Status LogId="123" LogDate="01/04/2017 03:08:44" StatusId="28" StatusTitle="test" AgentId="19" AgentName="test" AgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </StatusLog>
      <ActionLog>
        <Action LogId="123" ActionTypeId="73" ActionTypeName="test" MilestoneId="1" ActionDate="01/04/2017 03:08:44" ActionNote="test" AgentId="19" AgentName="test,test" AgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </ActionLog>
      <EmailLog>
        <Email LogId="123" SendDate="01/01/2017 20:53:39" EmailTemplateId="1" EmailTemplateName="test " AgentId="1" AgentName="test" AgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </EmailLog>
      <DistributionLog>
        <Distribution LogId="1" LogDate="01/01/2017 10:10:08" DistributionProgramId="1" DistributionProgramName="test" AssignedAgentId="1" AssignedAgentName="test,test" AssignedAgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </DistributionLog>
      <CreationLog LogId="1" LogDate="01/01/2017 10:10:05" Imported="true" CreatedByAgentId="1" CreatedByAgentName="test, test" CreatedByAgentEmail="test@test.com" />
    </Logs>
  </Lead>
</Leads>
```

Do you to work concerns, I can not post the entire xml string but it follows the structure above. According to a xml validator the xml is correct, however when I make another API call and get a different xml string back it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>\r\n<Leads>\r\n  <Lead Id="123" />\r\n  <Lead Id="456" />\r\n</Leads>'
```

I can successfully pass above xml into a dataframe using this code:

```
class XML2DataFrame:

    def __init__(self, xml_data):
        self.root = ET.XML(xml_data)

    def parse_root(self, root):
        """Return a list of dictionaries from the text
         and attributes of the children under this XML root."""
        return [self.parse_element(child) for child in iter(root)]

    def parse_element(self, element, parsed=None):
        """ Collect {key:attribute} and {tag:text} from thie XML
         element and all its children into a single dictionary of strings."""
        if parsed is None:
            parsed = dict()

        for key in element.keys():
            if key not in parsed:
                parsed[key] = element.attrib.get(key)
            else:
                raise ValueError('duplicate attribute {0} at element {1}'.format(key, element.getroottree().getpath(element)))           


        """ Apply recursion"""
        for child in list(element):
            self.parse_element(child, parsed)

        return parsed

    def process_data(self):
        """ Initiate the root XML, parse it, and return a dataframe"""
        structure_data = self.parse_root(self.root)
        return pd.DataFrame(structure_data)

xml2df = XML2DataFrame(xml_data)
xml_dataframe = xml2df.process_data()
```

However when I pass the xml string that is potentially malformed into the above function I get error:

```
AttributeError: 'xml.etree.ElementTree.Element' object has no attribute 'getroottree'
```

Since the potentially malformed xml has multiple values in the same tag, I think the function can not parse it.

I want the potentially malformed xml pushed into a flat dataframe.

Edit output row column headers from xml:

```
 ActionCount           CreateDate Flagged      Id LastDistributionDate  LeadFormType                                   LeadTitle LogCount FieldId                 FieldTitle FieldType                          Value CampaignId  CampaignTitle  AgentEmail AgentId     AgentName              LogDate   LogId  StatusId       StatusTitle AssignedAgentEmail AssignedAgentId AssignedAgentName DistributionProgramId DistributionProgramName              LogDate   LogId
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since, you updated the question, i decided to post another answer with the new xml.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

xml = """
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Leads>
      <Lead Id="123" LeadTitle="test, test.,  , (123) 456-7890, " CreateDate="01/01/2017 11:11:11" ModifyDate="01/04/2017 03:03:03" ACount="1" LCount="4" RCount="0" ROnly="false" Flagged="false" LastDistributionDate="01/01/2017 10:10:10" LeadFormType="test test">
    <Campaign CampaignId="123" CampaignTitle="abc" />
    <Status StatusId="123" StatusTitle="test" />
    <Agent AgentId="123" AgentName="test, test" AgentEmail="a@a.com">
      <AgentCustomFields custom1="test test, test" custom2="test" custom3="" custom4="" />
    </Agent>
    <Fields>
      <Field FieldId="7" Value="a@a.com" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="test" />
      <Field FieldId="8" Value="test" FieldTitle="test 1" FieldType="test" />
      <Field FieldId="9" Value="test" FieldTitle="City" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="10" Value="test" FieldTitle="State" FieldType="State" />
      <Field FieldId="11" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Zip" />
      <Field FieldId="950" Value="test." FieldTitle="Business Name" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1261" Value="Intuit Desktop" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1262" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1263" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Number" />
      <Field FieldId="1267" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Text" />
      <Field FieldId="1310" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Phone" />
      <Field FieldId="1319" Value="test" FieldTitle="test" FieldType="Number" />
      <Field FieldId="1485" Value="test" FieldTitle="tst" FieldType="State" />
    </Fields>
    <Logs>
      <StatusLog>
        <Status LogId="123" LogDate="01/04/2017 03:08:44" StatusId="28" StatusTitle="test" AgentId="19" AgentName="test" AgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </StatusLog>
      <ActionLog>
        <Action LogId="123" ActionTypeId="73" ActionTypeName="test" MilestoneId="1" ActionDate="01/04/2017 03:08:44" ActionNote="test" AgentId="19" AgentName="test,test" AgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </ActionLog>
      <EmailLog>
        <Email LogId="123" SendDate="01/01/2017 20:53:39" EmailTemplateId="1" EmailTemplateName="test " AgentId="1" AgentName="test" AgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </EmailLog>
      <DistributionLog>
        <Distribution LogId="1" LogDate="01/01/2017 10:10:08" DistributionProgramId="1" DistributionProgramName="test" AssignedAgentId="1" AssignedAgentName="test,test" AssignedAgentEmail="test@test.com" />
      </DistributionLog>
      <CreationLog LogId="1" LogDate="01/01/2017 10:10:05" Imported="true" CreatedByAgentId="1" CreatedByAgentName="test, test" CreatedByAgentEmail="test@test.com" />
    </Logs>
  </Lead>
</Leads>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
# Get Attributes from all nodes
attrs = []
for elm in soup():  # soup() is equivalent to soup.find_all()
    attrs.append(elm.attrs)

# Since you want the data in a dataframe, it makes sense for each field to be a new row consisting of all the other node attributes
fields_attribute_list= [x for x in attrs if 'FieldId' in x.keys()]
other_attribute_list = [x for x in attrs if 'FieldId' not in x.keys() and x != {}]

# Make a single dictionary with the attributes of all nodes except for the `Field` nodes.
attribute_dict = {}
for d in other_attribute_list:
    for k, v in d.items():  
        attribute_dict.setdefault(k, v)

# Update each field row with attributes from all other nodes.
full_list = []
for field in fields_attribute_list:
    field.update(attribute_dict)
    full_list.append(field)

# Make Dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(full_list)
```

However, note that this method overwrites attribute id's with the same name such as `LogId` in your xml. Anyhow, this code should help you get started.

Comment: Thank you very much, for the line `field.update(super_dict)` is super_dict supposed to be an empty dictionary? because I am gettting error 'undefined name super_dict'

Comment: Oh, sorry. made a mistake while reformatting. Use `attribute_dict` instead of `super_dict`

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find `BeautifulSoup` much easier for doing XML/HTML parsing. It also deals with malformed XML's and HTML's very well.

`pip install beautifulsoup4`

The following is how to parse the xml you've provided with BeautifulSoup.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 
import pandas as pd

xml = """
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Leads>
    <Lead Id="123" LeadTitle="test, test.,  , (123) 456-7890, " CreateDate="01/01/2017 11:11:11" ModifyDate="01/04/2017 03:03:03" ACount="1" LCount="4" RCount="0" ROnly="false" Flagged="false" LastDistributionDate="01/01/2017 10:10:10" LeadFormType="test test"></Lead>
    <Lead Id="123" />
    <Lead Id="456" />
</Leads>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(xml, "xml")
leads = soup.findAll('Lead')
lead_list = []
for lead in leads:
    lead_list.append(lead.attrs)

df = pd.DataFrame(lead_list)
df
```

Output:

```
ACount  CreateDate  Flagged Id  LCount  LastDistributionDate    LeadFormType    LeadTitle   ModifyDate  RCount  ROnly
0   1   01/01/2017 11:11:11 false   123 4   01/01/2017 10:10:10 test test   test, test., , (123) 456-7890,  01/04/2017 03:03:03 0   false
1   NaN NaN NaN 123 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   NaN NaN NaN 456 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it works great for Leads. However I put in the remaining XML which does not get sorted. How can I adapt your code to take in the entire xml string I posted?

Comment: Well, its basically the same principal. `Lead` is a node in the XML DOM, and `soup.findAll()` can be used to query all nodes in the XML. `lead.attrs` is a dictionary representation of all the attributes of the node. However, what i showed you above was how to make a row with the `Lead` node. Mixing up rows/nodes might be a little more challenging. I could probably help you if you show me the rest of your xml structure.

Comment: I posted the remaining XML under the previous example. That is all there is. Using your method I can go into each element and write it as a dataframe.

Comment: Can you provide an example of what an output row from that xml should look like?

Comment: I made the output row. Its all of the values in the xml that are before any value that has a equal sign.Hope that makes sense.